# Update of of Composite Entity fails

Tags: java, hibernate

I have Person entity which has composition with Location Entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =
{ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@Cascade(
{org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
public Location getLocation()
{
    return location;
}
```

And Location Entity has Name as Id

```
@Id
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

I am getting following Exception when Person's location is changed from L1 to L2 in Spring MVC form where this Person entity is modelAttribute for the form.

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException:identifier of an instance of com.x.y.z.Location was altered from L2 to L1; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.x.y.z.Location was altered from L2 to L1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) with [Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_association).

What you have mapped is an association; composition in Hibernate (JPA) is mapped via `@Embeddable` / `@Embedded` annotations. Associations are relationships between separate entities; they are usually connected via entity identifiers (foreign keys in the database).

In your particular case, `Person` entity points to `Location` entity which means in the database `PERSONS` table has a `LOCATION_ID` foreign key (names may differ) to `LOCATIONS` table. What you're trying to do is to update that key on `Location` end which is illegal because it would sever Hibernate's relationship (the other end still holds the previous key value internally).

Primary keys should generally be surrogate and not updatable to begin with; if you do need to "update" it you'll have to either disassociate `Location` from `Person`, update `Location` and  assign it to `Person` again OR create a brand new `Location` instance and assign that to your `Person`.

All that said, if you're really trying to model Composition relationship, you need to replace @ManyToOne with @Embedded and change your table schema accordingly. Here's a link to 
 Hibernate Annotations documentation on [mapping components](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e569).

Also, specifying cascade types in two separate annotations (JPA vs Hibernate extension) is not a good thing. If you really need the Hibernate extension one (which you don't in this case), just use it and leave `cascade` attribute in JPA annotations empty.

Answer (score 0):

I done same thing in standalone application . The thing works. I think it should be some problem with @modelAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your Location entity attribute id **type has been changed in your model class**.Please refer *the id and mapping attribute id types are same*.Make sure that id attribute **getter and setter function return types.**